# I got Internet when connected directly to the modem but not when connected (wired) to the Router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

it has been a while since I've been looking for answers to my problem on the page, but nothing which helps yet.

I have the next problem, a while ago I used to have a router netgear WNR1000 v3 connected to a modem (which service originally allow only two connected devices), hence by using my Router I could connect as many as I wanted, it worked perfectly. For some reasons I change my ISP to test other service and everything was ok as well, even though I decided to go back to the first provider that I used to have (everything worked perfectly fine before) but now I cannot get any internet through the router... BUT when I connect the laptop directly to the modem it works perfectly ok.

the router led indicates there is internet and so does the windows indicator, but when trying to surf, any navegator saids connection time out and no web page is charged.

I have tried to:

- change the MAC address to the modem for the computer one.
- Fix the IP address on the router.
- hard reset either modem and router
- update the router firmware

I also

- Ping the router : works
- Ping an internet address: Fails
- Connect other device to the router (wireless), there is not internet either

here are some pieces of further information:
Host system: Windows 10 pro

*MODEM CONEXTION (Excellent internet)

IPv4                    172.16.251.253

Subnet Mask             255.255.255.0

Default Gateway             172.16.251.254

DHCP server. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.55.55

When connected to the Router

Dirección IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.2

Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0

Default Gateway        . . . . . : 192.168.1.1

DHCP server . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1*

I would really appreciate your help

Kind regards,

JPC

Comment: Have you tried a different router?

Comment: I find the DHCP IP address when you connect to the modem a bit confusing. It is on another subnet? But why hook a router up to your modem? Why not just a switch and then a normal access point to get wifi? Seems the modem handles routing and DHCP (or whatever the 192.168.55.55 device is).

Comment: If the modem is doing DHCP, then maybe disable it in the router, essentially making it a switch.

Comment: I once worked on a friend's network and had the same issue as you.  He was connecting to the wireless at a trailer park.  The park had a commercial wireless system with an IP range in the 10.0.0. range.  It got its internet from a modem router with an IP range of 192.168.0.  That was the same IP range on the network I was trying to get to work.  My suggestion is to do a traceroute to see what IP addresses are returned before it gets to the internet while the computer is connected to the modem.

Comment: Try a different etherner cable just in case...

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys, 
Different router is not available, but as I just said, it used to work perfectly fine on this set up.

Cable double checked, its ok.

The reason I want to do the set up in this way is because orinally my ISP allow only 2 devices conections, and I made it to bypass it before by doing this kind of set up.

Answer (score 0):

I've run the suggested tests, here are the results

When connected directly to the modem:

I've run the tracer tests, here are the results:

When connected directly to the "modem" (which in reality is a router)

> tracert google.com
>
> Traza a la dirección google.com [173.194.112.137]
>   sobre un máximo de 30 saltos:
>
> 1    14 ms    13 ms    14 ms  172.16.251.254
>
> 2    16 ms    16 ms    17 ms  79.143.140.25
>
> 3    15 ms    15 ms    15 ms  google2.franceix.net [37.49.236.2]
>
> 4    15 ms    15 ms    15 ms  72.14.238.234
>
> 5    27 ms    16 ms    16 ms  209.85.245.83
>
> 6    32 ms    25 ms    26 ms  72.14.235.14
>
> 7    30 ms    25 ms    25 ms  fra07s31-in-f9.1e100.net [173.194.112.137]

When connected to the router:

> tracert google.com
>
> Traza a la dirección google.com [173.194.113.6]
>   sobre un máximo de 30 saltos:
>
> 1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.1
>
> 2     *        *        *     Tiempo de espera agotado para esta solicitud.
>
> 3     *        *        *     Tiempo de espera agotado para esta solicitud.

Finally, I have tried to disable the DHCP on the router, but no change.

Again, when I run ipconfig /all, I get this:

By router

> Adaptador de Ethernet Ethernet:
>
> Sufijo DNS específico para la conexión. . :
>
> Descripción . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Qualcomm Atheros AR8171/8175 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (NDIS 6.30)
>
> Dirección física. . . . . . . . . . . . . : 20-25-64-79-1D-2F
>
> DHCP habilitado . . . . . . . . . . . . . : sí
>
> Configuración automática habilitada . . . : sí
>
> Vínculo: dirección IPv6 local. . . : fe80::e1ac:5f41:2e75:112d%2(Preferido)
>
> Dirección IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.2(Preferido)
>
> Máscara de subred . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
>
> Concesión obtenida. . . . . . . . . . . . : sábado, 3 de octubre de 2015 
>   9:47:12 p. m.
>     La concesión expira . . . . . . . . . . . : domingo, 4 de octubre de 2015
>   9:47:12 p. m.
>
> Puerta de enlace predeterminada . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
>
> Servidor DHCP . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
>
> IAID DHCPv6 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 35661156
>
> DUID de cliente DHCPv6. . . . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1D-63-F6-DE-20-25-64-79-1D-2F
>
> Servidores DNS. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
>
> NetBIOS sobre TCP/IP. . . . . . . . . . . : habilitado

But when connected to the Modem:

>

> Adaptador de Ethernet Ethernet:
>
> Sufijo DNS específico para la conexión. . :
>
> Descripción . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Qualcomm Atheros AR8171/8175 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (NDIS 6.30)
>
> Dirección física. . . . . . . . . . . . . : 20-25-64-79-1D-2F
>
> DHCP habilitado . . . . . . . . . . . . . : sí
>
> Configuración automática habilitada . . . : sí
>
> Dirección IPv6 . . . . . . . . . . : fc01::e1ac:5f41:2e75:112d(Preferido)
>
> Dirección IPv6 temporal. . . . . . : fc01::953a:f3f:ef25:6138(Preferido)
>
> Vínculo: dirección IPv6 local. . . : fe80::e1ac:5f41:2e75:112d%2(Preferido)
>
> Dirección IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.251.252(Preferido)
>
> Máscara de subred . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
>
> Concesión obtenida. . . . . . . . . . . . : sábado, 3 de octubre de 2015 9:58:15 p. m.
>
> La concesión expira . . . . . . . . . . . : sábado, 3 de octubre de 2015 10:58:14 p. m.
>
> Puerta de enlace predeterminada . . . . . : fe80::213:33ff:fec7:3a34%2
>
> ```
>                                   fe80::213:33ff:fec7:3be2%2
>
>                                   fe80::213:33ff:fec7:3b51%2
>
>
>
>           ....( Several of this kind, around 30) ....
>
>
>                                   fe80::213:33ff:fec7:3d72%2
>
>                                   172.16.251.254
> ```
>
> Servidor DHCP . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.55.55
>
> IAID DHCPv6 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 35661156
>
> DUID de cliente DHCPv6. . . . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1D-63-F6-DE-20-25-64-79-1D-2F
>
> Servidores DNS. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.55.55
>
> NetBIOS sobre TCP/IP. . . . . . . . . . . : habilitado